# Sqoop export using update key

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop2

I have to export HDFS file into MySql.
Let's say my HDFS file is:

```
1,abcd,23
2,efgh,24
3,ijkl,25
4,mnop,26
5,qrst,27
```

and say my Mysql database schema is:

```
+-----+-----+-------------+
| ID  | AGE |    NAME     |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|     |     |             |
+-----+-----+-------------+
```

When I'm inserting using following Sqoop command:

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBNAME \
--username root \
--password root \
--export-dir /input/abc \
--table test \
--fields-terminated-by "," \
--columns "id,name,age"
```

It's working fine and inserting into database.

But, when I need to update already existing records I have to use `--update-key` and `--columns`.

Now, when I'm trying to update table using following command:

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBNAME \
--username root \
--password root \
--export-dir /input/abc \
--table test \
--fields-terminated-by "," \
--columns "id,name,age" \
--update-key id
```

I'm facing issue like data is not updating into columns as specified in `--columns`

Am I doing anything wrong?

Can't we update database this way? HDFS file should be in Mysql schema only to update?

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Just incase you are still searching for an answer, I will need more clarifications. Are you getting any errors or it simply isn't updating the columns as you expect?

Answer (score 9):

4b.Update data from HDFS into a table in a relational database

Create emp table tbl in mysql test db

```
create table emp
(
id int not null primary key,
name varchar(50)
);
```

vi emp --> create file with below contents

```
1,Thiru
2,Vikram
3,Brij
4,Sugesh
```

Move the file to hdfs

```
hadoop fs -put emp <dir>
```

Execute the below sqoop job to export the data to the mysql

```
sqoop export --connect <jdbc connection> \
--username sqoop \
--password sqoop \
--table emp \
--export-dir <dir> \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',';
```

Verify the data in the mysql table

```
mysql> select * from emp;

+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Thiru  |
|  2 | Vikram |
|  3 | Brij   |
|  4 | Sugesh |
+----+--------+
```

update the emp file & move the updated file into hdfs.
contents of the updated file

```
1,Thiru
2,Vikram
3,Sugesh
4,Brij
5,Sagar
```

Sqoop export for upsert - Update if the key matches else insert.

```
sqoop export --connect <jdbc connection> \
--username sqoop \
--password sqoop \
--table emp \
--update-mode allowinsert \
--update-key id \
--export-dir <dir> \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',';

Note: --update-mode <mode> - we can pass two arguments "updateonly" - to update the records. this will update the records if the update key matches.
if you want to do upsert (If exists UPDATE else INSERT) then use "allowinsert" mode.
example: 
--update-mode updateonly \ --> for updates
--update-mode allowinsert \ --> for upsert
```

verify the results:

```
mysql> select * from emp;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Thiru  |
|  2 | Vikram |
|  3 | Sugesh |--> Previous value "Brij"
|  4 | Brij   |--> Previous value "Sugesh"
|  5 | Sagar  |--> new value inserted
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try with `--update-key primary_key`

```
 sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBNAME -username root -password root --export-dir /input/abc --table test --fields-terminated-by "," --update-key id
```

It worked for me.It updates all records matching with primary key. (It may not insert new data)

Make use of  `--update-mode updateonly/allowinsert` wisely

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try with --input-fields-terminated-by. 
Currently you are using fields-terminated-by, which is meant for imports.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried this on Sqoop using in multiple ways. The Update-Key can only update the columns already present in the table and can't insert them unless you also mention the Update-Mode to allowinsert (which is not supported by all databases). If you actually try to update using update-key it will update the rows for the mentioned key in update-key.